# Jquery - Two drop down menus

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdown menus which displays and hides div elements depending on which option you choose. I want to change the div classes to tr classes but I can't get it to work. How should I rewrite the jquery code to make it work on tr classes?

Here is the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6PrQW/1/) with the code

Here is the jquery code which I Believe should be rewritten.

```
$("select.filterby").change(function(){
    var filters = $.map($("select.filterby").toArray(), function(e){
        return $(e).val();
    }).join(".");
    $("div#FilterContainer").find("div").hide();
    $("div#FilterContainer").find("div." + filters).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML code:

```
   <p>Filter: </p>
            <select class="filterby">
            <option value="all"><h5>Show All</h5></option>
            <option value="1"><h5>One</h5></option>
            <option value="2"><h5>Two</h5></option>
            <option value="3"><h5>Three</h5></option>
          </select>



      <p>Location: </p>
        <select class="filterby">
        <option value="all"><h5>All Locations</h5></option>
        <option value="nj"><h5>NJ</h5></option>
        <option value="ny"><h5>NY</h5></option>
        <option value="pa"><h5>PA</h5></option>
      </select>


  <table id="FilterContainer">
<tbody>
  <tr><td class="all 1 nj">Test One NJ</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="all 1 ny">Test One NY</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="all 1 pa">Test One PA</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="all 2 nj">Test Two NJ</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="all 2 ny">Test Two NY</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="all 2 pa">Test Two PA</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="all 3 nj">Test Three NJ</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="all 3 ny">Test Three NY</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="all 3 pa">Test Three PA</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="all 1 nj">Test One NJ</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="all 1 pa">Test One PA</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="all 1 pa">Test One PA</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="all 2 nj">Test Two NJ</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="all 2 ny">Test Two NY</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="all 2 ny">Test Two NY</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JS code:

```
$("select.filterby").change(function(){
    var filters = $.map($("select.filterby").toArray(), function(e){
        return $(e).val();
    }).join(".");
    $("table#FilterContainer").find("td").hide();
    $("table#FilterContainer").find("td." + filters).show();
});
```

Comment: Possible to filter entire rows, the <tr> element. And can you send a working jsfiddle? :)

Comment: Made it to work. Only changed td to tr but thanks mate! Works great!

Answer (score 0):

By "tr classes", I assume you mean tr elements with specific classes determined by your filter array.

You would make your div with an id of FilterContainer into a table

```
<table id="FilterContainer">
    <tr class="all 1 ng"><td>...</td></tr>
    ....
</table>
```

and your selectors would be as follows:

```
$("#FilterContainer tr").hide();
$("#FilterContainer tr").show();
```

Comment: Mind to send a working JSFiddle? Mine won't work! And yes, that was what I ment :)